# How to get model from plugin?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-cms

My model:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="uploads/images/")
    content = HTMLField(blank=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(always_update=True,populate_from='title', unique=True) 
    date_created = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today())
```

CMS Plugin:

```py
class PostPlugin(CMSPlugin):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Register plugin:

```py
@plugin_pool.register_plugin
class CMSPostPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    model = PostPlugin
    name = _("Post")
    render_template = "post/post.html"
    allow_children = True
    admin_preview = True
    module = "subpage"

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context.update({
            'post':instance.post,
            'instance':instance,
            'placeholder':placeholder
        })
        return context
```

So, after that, I add this to my database, the intermediate table was created. Here a screenshot.
[table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VM2r.png)

This is how I get the plugin instances:

```
CMSPlugin.objects.filter(plugin_type='CMSPostPlugin', placeholder_id=placehoder.id)
```

Subsequently, I want to get the `Post` model from this intermediate table, but I don't know how to do that.

Of course, I can hardcode it like get a table by name and then get post id, but maybe there is a "normal" solution for Django CMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
plugin_instance = (
    CMSPlugin.objects
        .filter(plugin_type='CMSPostPlugin', placeholder_id=placehoder.id)
        .first()
)

post_model_instance = PostModel.get(id=plugin_instance.id)

post = post_model_instance.post
```

It seems that the `id`s of the `CMSPlugin` instance and its model are identical.